# How to read and combine multiple nts files

Tags: r

I am trying to read and combine several nts files that contain 3D landmark data e.g. my.ply.nts, my.ply2.nts etc...
I am using the geomorph package to try and perform a GPA on the data.

I want to use the `readmulti.nts` function to read and combine my nts files but I literally do not know how to write the code to do this.
I feel like it should be pretty simple so please help!

The argument for the function is a filelist - a vector containing the file paths to all the nts files to be compiled but I don't know how to go about writing this.
Thanks

Comment: Write code that creates sample files in a particular location. Then examples can be written and tested.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is getting a vector of your file paths, put all your nts files into a folder. Then, use the `list.files` function, replacing "mydirectory" with the path to the folder where your nts files are. This creates a vector of filenames for you to use with `readmulti.nts`.

```
myfiles <- list.files(path="mydirectory", full.names=TRUE)
mydata <- readmulti.nts(myfiles)
```